# Why is my object formulating differently in the console than it is when I run it through Tidy JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My Array of Objects is not appearing the way I want it to when I print it to the console. When I put it through Tidy JS, it formats it correctly. When I print it to the console, it looks incorrect.

What I want it to look like is:

```
Array
    Object
        Key:Value
        Key:Value
        Array
            Object
                Object
            Object
                Object
```

But instead its prints out how it does in this codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLrgKg

Any ideas as to why formatting it like it is in this codepen instead of how I want it to be?

```
var ArrayOfBlocks1 = [
{
ID:"1",
block: "block1",
BlockElements: [
  { blockElement1: { QuestionID: "1" } },
  { blockElement2: { QuestionID: "2" } },

]
},
{
ID:"2",
block: "block2",
BlockElements: [
  { blockElement1: { QuestionID: "1" } },
  { blockElement2: { QuestionID: "2" } }
]
},
{
ID:"3",
block: "block3",
BlockElements: [
  { blockElement1: { QuestionID: "1" } },
  { blockElement2: { QuestionID: "2" } }
]
}
];
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what's going wrong, or even what you expect. Post the expected outcome *here* in your question, and describe how the actual result differs from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the first element in the array rather then the whole array.

Change line 42 from `console.log(ArrayOfBlocks1[0])` to `console.log(ArrayOfBlocks1)`